# List collection that replaces numbers with words

Tags: c#

I am trying to improve a list collection that i have to replace values that are divisible by two and 10 and replace everything that is divisible by two with dTwo and ten with dTen?

My code works with one divisible statment but not two.

```
        var num = new List<string>();

        for (int n = 0; n < 101; n++)
        {
            num.Add(n % 2 == 0 ? "dTwo"   : n.ToString());
            num.Add(n % 10 == 0 ? "dTen" : n.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: What's wrong with that code? Do you not want to add both entries for something that is divisible by both, ie 20?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since any number that is divisible by 10 is also divisible by 2 you have to switch your addition statements, and continue with the next number if you have a number divisible by 10:

```
    var num = new List<string>();

    for (int n = 0; n < 101; n++)
    {
        if( n % 10 == 0)
        {
           num.Add("dTen");
        }
        else num.Add(n % 2 == 0 ? "dTwo" : n.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: if I am not mistaken, that will never perform the `n % 2` test. The `continue` runs unconditionally in your sample.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the question, but that would always ignore the divisible-by-two check, would it not?

Answer (score 1):

If I can I try avoid using loop controls out side of the defined construct of the actual loop, ie. I prefer to avoid using `continue` if I can, it sort of feels like using `goto` statements. For this case, I would go for the plain and simple approach which I believe is readable, maintainable and simple albeit a little more verbose.

You can switch the order of the if/else if statements to change the priority if required, in this case the `n % 10` has priority

```
var num = new List<string>();
for (int n = 0; n < 101; ++n)
{
  if (n % 10 == 0)
  {
    num.Add("dTen");
  }
  else if (n % 2 == 0)
  { 
    num.Add("dTwo");
  }
  else
  {
    num.Add(n.ToString());
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 You are right, I don't know what I was thinking ;-) This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Nitpick, but is 0 divisible by 10? ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches I would take here, the first is verbose, but conveys what you're trying to do in a very readable manner:

```
var num = new List<string>(101);
for (int i = 0; i < 101 ; i++)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        num.Add(i.ToString());
    }
    else if (i % 10 == 0)
    {
        num.Add("dTen");
    }
    else if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        num.Add("dTwo");
    }
    else
    {
        num.Add(i.ToString());
    }
}
```

The second uses a more concise LINQ-y type approach, like this.

```
var num = Enumerable.Range(0, 101)
    .Select(
        n => n == 0 ? n.ToString() : 
        n % 10 == 0 ? "dTen" : 
        n % 2 == 0 ? "dTwo" : 
        n.ToString())
    .ToList();
```

Note that I've also taken into account the 0 edge case, where 0 would otherwise get reported as being divisible by 10.

Which one you go for is largely up to your taste. Personally I'd go for the latter implementation, as it's concise but still conveys the intent of the code. Some very rudimentary tests I've just done shows that it'll execute faster as well.